# Javascript Regex to match comma delimited duplicate strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for comma delimited strings.

ex: "Test1, Test2, Test3, Test1"

Basically:

```
rgx.test("Test1, Test2, Test3, Test1")
```

should return false since there is a duplicate.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the solution be a function and not a `RegEx`, here is a code that works fine.

```
function isSetString(str, separator) {
    //TODO input validation
    var arr = str && str.split(separator || ","),
        l = arr && arr.length,
        o = {}; 

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty( arr[i] )) {
            return false;
        } else {
            o[ arr[i] ] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "test1, test2,test1, ....";
String parts[] = s.split(",");
```

Then all your tokens are in `parts[]` and you can just traverse through that to see if any 2 match. Use a nested for loop. One to run over each, and another to compare to those ahead in the array

Comment: If the input is huge, the CPU performance will not be optimal. You could change the performance from O(n^2) to O(n) by using a hash table. In JS you can achieve this with plain `objects`.

Comment: Actually, @OrangePot, you code is not `JavaScript`!

Comment: Its not quite O(n^2) cause youre only looking ahead in the array. But yes, not the most efficient way, but the easiest way to implement if input is small.

Comment: @Ricardo aww yea... been caught up in a lot of java lately, misread

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

```
(?:^|,)([^,]+)(?=.*,\1(?:,|$))
```

[**See Regex 101 Demo here.**](https://regex101.com/r/pS3wW6/2)

Please note that I've taken the liberty of removing spaces from your comma-delimited list. It just makes things easier.